# list - show default enter on load

Tags: jquery, list, show-hide

I'm trying to show a default entry from a dropdown list.
Currently when I click on a link the result is expanded below.. this works well.

But on load I'd like to show a default entry.

I've tried doing it using this, but it has made no difference.

```
var elem = $('#3').next('.qst')
$('.qst').not(elem).hide(800);
elem.toggle(850);
```

I've created a fiddle showing what I've got: https://jsfiddle.net/84sk48mf/

Any ideas how I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this simple way..

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/84sk48mf/4/)

```
        var elem = $('#3');  //based on the id, it will expand
     $('.qst').hide(800);  //by default it will hide all the elements  
         elem.toggle(850);
```

**Or You want to hide the first element ? Try this way**

```
var elem = $('#list li:first-child').find(".qst");
      $('.qst').hide(800);
        elem.toggle(850);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few things to note**

---

> - **`id` for any element doesn't and shouldn't begin with numbers.**
>
>   - For `HTML4` `ID` and `NAME` tokens must begin with a letter `([A-Za-z])` and may be followed by any number of letters, digits
>       `([0-9])`, hyphens `("-")`, underscores `("_")`, colons `(":")`, and
>       periods `(".")`.
>   - `HTML5` is even more permissive, saying only that an `id` must contain at least **one character** and may not contain any **space
>       characters**.
> - **`element attribute value` should be enclosed with `" "`, here `id` value should be enclosed with `" "`, Also it will be good if you
>     have `attribute values` wrapped within `" "` instead of `' '`.**
> - **You don't need to specify both `display:block;display:none` inside single `style` because, the later one will work and sooner one
>     will be of no use.**

Just changed your `id` for each `element` and `show` the `element` on `DOM ready` as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.linky').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(this).next('.qst')
        $('.qst').not(elem).hide(800);
        elem.toggle(850);
    });
    var elem = $('#m3')
    elem.show(850);
});
```

```css
.qst {
    color: black;
    width: 750px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    line-height: 150%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#" class="linky"> Q1 ?</a>
        <div class="qst" style="display:none;" id="m0"><strong>Q. 1 ?</strong>
            <br/> ANSWER 1
        </div>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="linky"> Q2 ?</a>
        <div class="qst" style="display:none;" id="m1"><strong>Q. 2 ?</strong>
            <br/> ANSWER 2
        </div>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="linky"> Q3 ?</a>
        <div class="qst" style="display:none;" id="m2"><strong>Q. 3 ?</strong>
            <br/>
            <br/> ANSWER 3
        </div>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="linky"> Q4 ?</a>
        <div class="qst" style="display:none;" id="m3"><strong>Q. 4 ?</strong>
            <br/> ANSWER 4
        </div>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="linky"> Q5 ?</a>
        <div class="qst" style="display:none;" id="m4"><strong>Q. 5 ?</strong>
            <br/> ANSWER 5
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```